# Getting a object has attribute error

Tags: python, attributes

So when I give the program the follow commands I get:

```
a = Drink(5)

b = AlcoholicDrink(4)

a. numberOfCalories

19.35

b.numberOfCalories
```

**This is where I get the error**

```
'AlcoholicDrink' object has  no attribute 'sugar'
```

I have tried adding in sugar attribute to the AlcoholicDrink class but still getting the same error any ideas?

```
class Drink:
    def __init__(self,sugar,drink = 0):
        self.sugar = sugar
        self.drink = drink

    def numberOfCalories(self):
        return self.sugar * 3.87

class AlcoholicDrink(Drink):
    def __init__(self,alcohol):       
        self.alcohol  = alcohol

    def numberOfCalories(self):
        if self.alcohol > 0:
            self.alcohol * 7.0 + self.sugar
        else:
            super.numberOfCalories()
```

Comment: where did you add the sugar attribute?

Comment: As you're coming from a Java/C# background, one difference is the base constructor doesn't automatically run if you override it in a derived class.

Comment: What @PeterWood said. Although to be accurate `__init__` is the instance _initializer_, the constructor is `__new__`; your classes are using the `__new__` method of the parent `object` class, since they don't override  `__new__` (and there's rarely a need to do so).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#super)`.__init__()` in the `__init__` for `AlcoholicDrink`. If you don't, the stuff in `Drink.__init__` won't run.

You should also add parameters for `sugar` and `drink` in the constructor for `AlcoholicDrink` and pass them to `super().__init__`. Here's an example:

```
class Drink:
    def __init__(self, sugar, drink=0):
        self.sugar = sugar
        self.drink = drink

    def number_of_calories(self):
        return self.sugar * 3.87

class AlcoholicDrink(Drink):
    def __init__(self, alcohol, sugar, drink=0):
        super().__init__(sugar, drink)       
        self.alcohol  = alcohol

    def number_of_calories(self):
        if self.alcohol > 0:
            return self.alcohol * 7.0 + self.sugar
        else:
            return super().number_of_calories()
```

You had a couple other issues with your code that I fixed:

- `AlcoholicDrink.number_of_calories` didn't return anything.
- You were missing parens after `super` in the else clause of `AlcoholicDrink.number_of_calories`
- [Method and function names in Python should be snake_case.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names)

Comment: I don't understand? Can you change the line and show me what it should look like?

Comment: @bradmonster I added a working example, let me know if that helps, or if you still have any questions.

Comment: Hey, for a = drink(4) and a.numberOfCalories this part works, but when type b = AlcoholicDrink(4) I get this error "__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sugar'"

Comment: @bradmonster Well, yeah. You need to either give `sugar` a default value or provide it when you create an instance of the class.

Comment: Thank you so much! Much help!

Comment: @bradmonster Glad I could help!

Comment: @MorganThrapp You are missing a `return` in the `else` case of `num_of_calories()` for the `AlcoholicDrink` class.

Comment: @lightalchemist Oops, thanks. I forget that you need that for `super()`.